# How to build package with cmake?

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

I want to build the package uci for ubuntu.

I download the source package and I found into the `C` files, `header` files and `CMakeLists.txt`

How to build the uci project with cmake?

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(uci C)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Os -Wall -Werror --std=gnu99 -g3 -I. -DUCI_PREFIX="${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

OPTION(UCI_PLUGIN_SUPPORT "plugin support" ON)
OPTION(UCI_DEBUG "debugging support" OFF)
OPTION(UCI_DEBUG_TYPECAST "typecast debugging support" OFF)
OPTION(BUILD_LUA "build Lua plugin" ON)

CONFIGURE_FILE( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/uci_config.h.in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/uci_config.h )

SET(LIB_SOURCES libuci.c file.c util.c delta.c parse.c)

ADD_LIBRARY(uci-shared SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(uci-shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME uci)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(uci-shared dl)

ADD_LIBRARY(uci-static STATIC ${LIB_SOURCES})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(uci-static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME uci)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(cli cli.c)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(cli PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME uci)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cli uci-shared dl)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(cli-static cli.c)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(cli-static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME uci-static)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cli-static uci-static dl)

ADD_LIBRARY(ucimap STATIC ucimap.c)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(ucimap-example ucimap-example.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ucimap-example uci-static ucimap dl)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lua)

INSTALL(FILES uci.h uci_config.h ucimap.h
    DESTINATION include
)

INSTALL(TARGETS uci-shared uci-static cli cli-static
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about this particular case, but the generic mode of operation with CMake is as follows. Let's assume you unpacked the package sources so that the CMakeList is located at `/some/path/to/source/CMakeLists.txt`. Then:

```
> cd /path/where/you/want/to/build
> mkdir package_name
> cd package_name
> cmake /some/path/to/source
```

Next, an optional step to launch (console) GUI to edit options, if necessary:

```
> ccmake
```

After you're happy with the setup:

```
> make
> make install
```

CMake also has a non-console GUI, but I've never used it on Unix, so I can't comment there. The basic idea would be the same, though: set up a build directory, point the GUI to the source directory (the one containing CMakeLists.txt), configure, modify uptions and reconfigure as necessary, generate Makefiles, exit GUI and run `make`.

Comment: you might want to set the installation path via `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install /path/to/src`

Comment: @Bort Yes, but note that the CMakeList sets it as well.

Comment: Yes. Setting it on the commandline overwrites the default or whatever is set in CMakeLists.txt. I just mention it here, because as a non root you cannot write to /usr/local (which is default on linux). Also, people new to cmake but familiar to autotools ./configure will most likely look for `--prefix` equivalent.

Comment: @Bort In this case, the command line doesn't take precedence, because the `set()` in the CMakeList doesn't include `CACHE`. It creates a non-cache variable which shadows the cache one.

Comment: you are right. I didn't look into the provided CMakeLists.txt file. The CMakeLists.txt file is actually doing it wrong. It should be handled like this: `IF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
        SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr" CACHE PATH "Foo install
                 prefix" FORCE)
ENDIF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)`